Confirming what happens when importing a package？
I was surprised to find out that both the two call in main.py works:
import package_top
package_top.module.hello() # I thought this won't work ...
package_top.hello() # I thought this is the only way

package_top
package_top/
├── __init__.py
└── module.py

__init__.py
from .module import hello

module.py
def hello():
    print("module_hello")

From my understanding, when I call import package_top in main.py, it will run __init__.py which adds hello to namespace package_top, and then package_top is added to namespace main, so I can access hello with package_top.hello(). What I don't understand is why the second call also works?
I expect the prgram to throw out an error at the second line.

The Python import machinery modifies the package_top module object and adds the module attribute as part of importing the child module. See the Python import docs on submodules:

When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. importlib APIs, the import or import-from statements, or built-in __import__()) a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object.

Other import statements such as from other_package import x, y only add the x and y names to the importing module object. In your case, from .module import hello, is both importing the function hello, and also importing the submodule module of package_top, so your import statement creates both package_top.hello and package_top.module, which in turn gives you access to package_top.module.hello.
You can confirm this by printing the module scope after importing:
from .module import hello

print(dir())

prints:
['__builtins__', (more default __stuff__ ...), 'hello', 'module']

Therefor package_top.module.hello() works without problems. Remove the from .module import hello statement and you will see the submodule is not imported, and the package_top.module.hello() statement will fail.

but the OP doesn't write import .module, the OP writes from .module import hello

@jkr, that doesn't seem to matter, printing dir() in the module still reveals the module attribute.

That's a weird inconsistency imho. And the question remains, why does module get added so? I don't see why it should.

It is part of the Python submodule import process, I linked to the docs stating it.

Thanks! Great answer! So my result can be explained by the import system doc. But I also want to ask why from top_module import xxx and from sub_module import xxx works differently in python.Why is it set like this? The inconsistency is really confusing.

Hi zicheng zhang, I'm not sure what you mean, could you edit your original question, or open a new question where you explain it fully? Your question is asked very well, which helped me answer. With this comment I don't have enough information to do so again :) thanks

Otherwise, if you consider your question fully answered, you can "accept" my answer, which gives me extra points (yay!) and lets the community know they don't need to look for another answer.
